# CakePHP URL Parameter

Tags: database, url, cakephp, parameters, get

How can I get the parameter in the URL and save it to a varialble so I can save it to my database?

> example: www.mydomain.com/item/products/3 <-

This is for my upload image, so I can specify what product ID will I use for that image.

```
function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Upload->create();

                if(empty($this->data['Upload']['image']['name'])) {
                    unset($this->request->data['Upload']['image']);
                }

                if(!empty($this->data['Upload']['image']['name'])) {
                    $filename = $this->request->data['Upload']['image']['name'];
                    $new_filename = STring::uuid().'-'.$filename;
                    $file_tmp_name = $this->request->data['Upload']['image']['tmp_name'];
                    $dir = WWW_ROOT.'img'.DS.'uploads';

                    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_name,$dir.DS.$new_filename);

                    $this->request->data['Upload']['image'] = $new_filename;
                    if($this->Upload->save($this->request->data)) {
                        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Uploaded.'));
                        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

How will I add it here. Thank you in advance :)
Im using cakePHP

Answer (score 1):

Just add the product id as a hidden input in the Form.
Then it will be included in the $this->data variable when you get the POST request.

Comment: how can I put the product id to the hidden field? Sorry newbie :|

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper::hidden

Comment: What if I want the id goes to other view? example: www.mydomain.com/item/products/view/3 -> www.mydomain.com/item/products/add/3.. That is the flow of my desire website..

Comment: Ok, If you are in the product page. You have a form to upload the image right? Then in that form just insert a hidden field. That field will be present in the data of the post. URL parameters are received via GET requests, forms do a POST request.

Comment: My upload image is in the "add" then before you can go there, you go first in the "view" so I can specify where the image will be putted. How will I pass the "id" to the hidden fields in the "add" ?

Comment: You obviously need an ADD view, or however you do it you need to have a form. Wherever the form is located you will have access to the product id, hence, then you will be able to add any inputs you wish.

Comment: Sorry still dont get it. How will the product_id from "view" to "add" because when I click the "Add image" , it will redirect me to www.mydomain.com/item/add , no parameters. Do I need to put the parameter to the link from the "view" ? How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

For example in a controller method like the following

```
public function product($id) {
  .....
}
```

You access it by the url (for example): `www.mydomain.com/item/products/3` where **Item** is the controller, **product** is the method you are calling in that controller and **3** represent a parameter that is required to the function to work in this case `$id`. (assuming you don't have any routing configuration)

Is treated as a normal php variable, just do whatever you wanna do with it. Just make sure you pass the correct value